# is 'do we actually know where we are going any more' a question?

Tags: british-english, questions, question-mark

I'm confused as to if

> do we actually know where we are going any more

is a question or not, because of the 'do' I think yes but when read it seems like a sentence.

Comment: It could be rhetorical but it is a question.

Comment: OK thank you, really threw me, was reading a newsletter and it had no question mark and I had to find out haha, thank you :)

Comment: Maybe some more context would explain the origin of your confusion... As you quoted it, without capitalisation, without any interpunction, it could be "an example phrase from a textbook that is not intended as an actual question"...

Comment: the context is a newsletter directed towards managers and saying how the financial woes are dispersing, do we actually know where we are going any more.  However, re-reading that I realsised it's incorrect grammatically, should be a but before the do and I'm guessing thats what threw me

Comment: Yes, it is a question.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the gut reaction "yes, it is a question because, um, it just is", we can actually approach this systematically. The sentence exhibits three characteristics that are of interest to us:

1. It says "do... know" rather than just "know",
2. it says "do we" rather than "we do",
3. and last but not least, it begins with a verb.

Each of these by itself can occur in a number of different scenarios:

1. "Do... know" could be an **emphatic** *do* ("I do like this"), or it could be an auxilliary *do* ([do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support)), and the latter could indicate a **question** ("Do we know?") or a **negation** ("We do not know").
2. "Do we" ([subject–auxiliary inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion)) could indicate a **question** ("Do we know?"), or **negative polarity** when there's a fronted adverbial that is a negative trigger ("Never/seldom/under no circumstances do we know").
3. A verb at the beginning could indicate a **question** ("Do we know?") or an **imperative** ("Do this now!") or a simple **ellipsis** ("I like whistling. Do it all the time.")

As you can see for yourself, the only scenario in which all three meet is a question.

Comment: Oh, and just for the sake of completeness: the omitted *but* you mentioned has no bearing on any of this. It's just a conjunction, and you can slap one of those onto the beginning of any sentence in any of those scenarios. "But I do like this". "But do we know?", "But we do not know", "But never do we know...", "But do this now!", "I hate whistling. But do it all the time."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a question. It begins with a word that can either be a question or an imperative/command, but the context of the statement, there is no action to take: "Do this task." versus "Do we do this task?"

Comment: This is basically right, but very poorly worded. You are really just looking for the terms *do-support* and *inversion*.